# spark auc and pr-auc not stable

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

when I try to use spark `BinaryClassificationEvaluator` , I will find that with same data and same raw prediction column and label col, evaluation result will change in multiple run. This will happen both in `auc` and `pr-auc`. Does this happen as expectation?